# How to get the second integer from a scanner in Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

How do I make B equal to the second integer found in the input by the scanner?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Learning {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner numberScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter two numbers");

        int a = numberScanner.nextInt();

        //int b =  the second number after a; 

    }

}
```

So how do I let java know that b is the second int after a?

Comment: Obvious answer is: "Same way you read it and stored in `a`". You need to be more precise about what is the hard part you are facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int b = numberScanner.nextInt();
```

Comment: Doesn't even attempt to explain *why*.

Comment: @AlmightyR I mean... does it need to? OP has already done it once, so they clearly know what this line of code does. I'd be curious to know why they thought doing it a second time wouldn't work though.

Comment: @MageXy *"OP has already done it once, so they clearly know what this line of code does."* - I don't mean to sound offensive, but, you do realize that the accepted answer here is telling him to repeat the code, and that if he knew how the code works, he wouldn't have asked in the first place, right? I see a big flaw in the answer, and, unlike most, I point it out and give the poster a chance to improve it, instead of doing a silent down-vote that doesn't tell neither poster nor readers what's wrong. This is etiquette that should be enforced here, but unfortunately, isn't.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Learning {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner numberScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter two numbers");

        System.out.println("Enter 1st number: ");

        int a = numberScanner.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter 2nd number: ");

        int b = numberScanner.nextInt();
    }

}
```

Comment: You are repeating the OP's code...*Why?*...Post the single line of code that is relevant, and explain that...There is no need for this clutter.

Answer (score 0):

Should be fairly intuitive:

`Scanner.`***`next`***`Int()`

In other words, you can do for B ***exactly the same*** that you did for A.

From [Java 8 docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--):

> Scans the next token of the input as an int. This method will throw InputMismatchException if the next token cannot be translated into a valid int value as described below. If the translation is successful, the scanner advances past the input that matched.
>
> If the next token matches the Integer regular expression defined above then the token is converted into an int value as if by removing all locale specific prefixes, group separators, and locale specific suffixes, then mapping non-ASCII digits into ASCII digits via Character.digit, prepending a negative sign (-) if the locale specific negative prefixes and suffixes were present, and passing the resulting string to Integer.parseInt

Comment: I didn't downvote, But I think the reason might be code-only answer, no explanation. Even thought the answer might be purely straight forward. Giving the code-only answer defies the purpose of answering a question. A little description might help others too.

Comment: @UmaKanth Except that the upvoted answers are not only *"code-only"* but also *less reasonable*...The accepted answer by poorvankBathia makes no effort to explain anything, and the other upvoted answer, by Muhammad, is filled with irrelevant code. Mine at least points to the word "next" in the method, highligting the context of the action performed by it, without unnecessary junk.

Comment: @UmaKanth There. Added a quote from the docs explaining the method, as well as the link to the complete doc.

Answer (score -2):

You can read the entire line, saving it in a string, and then with the method `charAt(int)`, get the second number and convert in int, as follows:

```
String str = new String();
str=read.nextLine();
char c = str.charAt(1);
int i = Integer.parseInt(c);
```

Comment: The reason your answer was down-voted was because this is not what the OP wanted.

Comment: Just misunderstood the question